# Payum : Get Payment from Notification Action

Tags: symfony, sylius, payum

I am beginner with payum. I succeed in developping a custom gateway which deals with status, convert, capture actions correctly. Now I get the reponse from the client, and I want to update order status from payment.

I do not use any controller, only action from Payum, so I have not any access to container, entity manager, and so on... (service also, so it is impossible to get entity manager via service in payum action)

In the notification action, I have a notify token, containing the Payment class (as string namespace) and the payment Id.

I just want to fetch current order from the payment object, but I dont find any way to use doctrine inside a payum notification action.

Can someone help me please ?

Thanks.

PS: I configure payum as explained in "documentation" (I use doctrine to store), currently i have nothing in Payment and PaymentToken Database tables (whereas I have done at least 150 payment test ^^)...

Comment: try $request->getFirstModel()

Comment: getFirstModel return current set model. From Notify Action we get null as model, and get bank information via GetHttpRequest (same use cas in be2bill gateway), therefore model is not right way in this use cas.

Comment: In Be2Bill gateway, there is no order update. Is there an automatic order update in Sylius / Payum ?

Comment: be2bill does not support notify url per payment (for security reasons they say). I did kind of work around to by pass this, maybe something does not work as expected.

Comment: Issue is solved using NotifyNullAction as securized call between bank and client application to run bank check (hash_mac), then on NotifyAction using Api with controller to confirm or cancel current order. Everything is securized via tokens (capture and notify token).